# Change uiwebview select color.

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How do I change the default (light blue color) when  ever any text is selected on uiwebview to  clear color or transparent?

Comment: Not sure if you (easily) can. However you probably can disable the selection of a text, is that what you want?

Comment: No, I like to keep the selection of text as I am using window.getSelection() in my JavaScript. It is just that the blue selection color does not go well with my overall theme hence I like to just change that color.

Comment: Plz go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642485/is-it-possible-to-change-text-selection-color-in-uiwebview-ios