# Is it possible to change text selection color in UIWebview ios?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, webview

I have load html file in UIwebview and had put below code in html file.

```
 <style>
  ::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
              color: red;
              background: yellow;
          }

      ::selection {
          color: red;
          background: yellow;
      }
      </style>
```

and also set tint color in Uiwebview but still it is showing blue color when i am selecting text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I wasted *2* days to resolve this headache issue.Visit This [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/Bvd9d/) and Place JS Code in your JS File.Import it in .HTML file.

Here's the sample code for it.

```
function highlight(colour) {
var range, sel;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    try {
        if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8 case
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}}
```

call this method by Objective-C code

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"highlight('#ff0')"];
```

Comment: Awesom! You saved me.

Comment: Hi @mohsin  .. I am trying to highlight text. But, I want permanently stored when user again open the app,, he can able to see existing highlights. How to do that??

Comment: @McDonal_11 Same things I also want to do. Do you find any solution?

Comment: We can Highlight text in UIWebView. But, we cant highlight text in PDF File which inside UIWebView. So I have tried own.

Comment: You have to use different library for that.