# How to create a Medium-like UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm exploring ways to play around text selection in UIWebView.

I really like how article view is done in Medium app and I'm wondering if it is possible to do in a standard WebView using custom JS or it must be done by implementing custom view with complex CoreText logic.

Features I'm interested to implement:

1. Custom color for a text selection and text selection controls (limits). 
   I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642485/is-it-possible-to-change-text-selection-color-in-uiwebview-ios/28644130) on SO but it doesn't seem to work
2. Limit selection by paragraphs. 
   I suppose that can be done by embedding JavaScript, but not too sure.
3. Custom "pop up". 
   It is straightforward how to remove or add actions form copy/paste popup menu. But how to display a custom one? If we can have a callback to UIViewController when text was selected - we can present a custom looking "bubble" with actions we need. I'm wondering if it is possible. Can't find a way to do it.

Comment: I also like the way Medium App doing with their content. Markdown might be other thing you can use.

Comment: Did you found an answer for this question?